# P4python Help Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I'm using P4Python to connect to a P4 server to retrieve results about some changes.

The ideal command on CLI is:

> p4 -p tcp:SERVER:1666 -u USER -P PASSWORD | p4 -p tcp:HOST:1666 -u USER  changes /path/...@$PROD_SHA_BUILD,@$SHA_BUILD

So I tried to replicate this via the python API:

```
    p4 = P4()
    p4.user = str(self.PERFORCE_USER)
    p4.password = str(self.PERFORCE_PASSWORD)
    p4.port = HOST
    p4.connect()
    per_user = "-u '" + str(self.PERFORCE_USER) + "'"
    per_passwd = "-P '" + str(self.PERFORCE_PASSWORD) + "'"
    cmd = "changes"
    tmp = p4.run(cmd,["//depot/se/development/HEAD/sports-navigation/...@823493,@828026",per_user,per_passwd])
```

Why am I getting the error that P4PASSWD is not defined?

I even added a:

```
os.environ["P4PASSWD"] = str(self.PERFORCE_PASSWORD)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that self.PERFORCE_PASSWORD is the correct password for whatever user name self.PERFORCE_USER refers to?

Comment: Yes I tested manually

Comment: Have the same experience, with the exception that it works on Windows, but not on Linux. Further, I am using the ticket based authentication. Could it be something with client versions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try the technique mentioned in [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html) for ticket based authentication?

```
from P4 import P4
p4 = P4()
p4.user = "Sven"
p4.password = "my_password"
p4.connect()
p4.run_login()
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! First I thought it was about all that settings being pushed in one go but for me it was actually just the login command that didn't work via `p4.run('login')` Seems you HAVE to use `p4.run_login()`!

Comment: Really weird that you have to use run_login... What's the point of connect() then? LOL